# Nitrosation of benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

How does benzene react with $\ce{NaNO2/HCl}$? Will $\ce{PhNO}$ be obtained? I [read](http://www.nature.com/srep/2013/131211/srep03481/full/srep03481.html?WT.ec_id=SREP-639%2C638-20140102) that pyridine can be produced under special conditions, but what will happen in some less exotic conditions?

Comment: Afaik, $\ce{NO^+}$-cation is too weak as electrophile to react with benzene, nitrosobenzene is obtained indirectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you noted, the link you provided was to a reaction run under rather exotic conditions (low-temperature plasma). Under more everyday laboratory conditions, for example, in solution, activated aromatic rings can react with $\ce{NO^+}$ as shown below.

[image]

However if there is a ring-activating amino substituent present, then the $\ce{NO^+}$ will react with the nitrogen to produce the synthetically important diazonium ion.

[image]