# Why other benzene derivatives do not undergo nitrosation

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

Solomon and Fryhle $11 th$ ed :

**Most other benzene derivatives except phenols and tertiary aromatic amines do not undergo C- nitrosation reaction**.

I agree that if there is a primary or secondary aromatic amine, the reaction will follow other routes but in case of other activating substituents EAS is the only route left for the electrophile $\ce{-^+N=O}$ for example with anisole.

Also it seems to contradict  [ron's answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15783/nitrosation-of-benzene)

So which one is correct?

Comment: I don't see any contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anisole can be nitrosated in good yield [reference here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239236262_Nitrosation_of_anisole_stability_constants_of_complexes_of_the_nitrosonium_ion_with_aromatic_nitroso_compounds_and_NMR_studies_of_restricted_rotation_in_the_complexes).  This, and other references, note that the PhOMe group is unstable to the reaction conditions being cleaved to give phenol.

m-Xylene can be nitrosated in good yield, o-xylene and toluene in modest yield in TFA or sulfuric/acetic acid mix under nitric oxide [reference here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239236180_Kinetics_and_mechanism_of_nitrosation_of_toluene_o-xylene_and_m-xylene_in_trifluoroacetic_acid_or_in_acetic-sulfuric_acid_mixtures_under_nitric_oxide)

Nitrosonium tetrafluoroborate will also nitrosate a range of electron-rich aromatics, including anisole and xylenes [reference here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00098a015?journalCode=joceah)

This suggests to me that the authors of the textbook quoted are in error, as two of the references predate the publication date of the textbook.